# Equality of continuous functions at endpoint

Tags: real-analysis

Say $f,g: [0,1) \to \mathbb R$ are continuous and equal on $[0,1)$. Does it follow that $f(1) = g(1)$?

Comment: At the moment, neither $f(1)$ nor $g(1)$ is defined. If $f,g\colon [0,1]\to \mathbb{R}$ are continuous, the answer is yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  Take $f(x) = x$ for $x\in[0,1]$ and $g(x) = x$ for $x\in[0,1)$ and $g(1) = 2$.